# Do I need to put a definite article "the" before then-current?

Tags: definite-article, hyphens

In a sentence:

> He considered visitors during {the?} then current off-season to be cognizant of bear presence in the area?

Also, should then-current be hyphenated?

Comment: Yes, need "the," and yes, probably should be hyphenated.

Comment: The reasoning behind hypenated *then-current* is because it is a two-word modifier, just like *two-word* is. Some people prefer that usage. A good general rule is that hyphens should be used only to avoid confusion or ambiguity. But some uses, such as *off-season* are customary, although the trend over time is always toward getting rid of the hyphen, thus the use of *offseason* by some. Just like *to-day* and *to-morrow* used to be the standard spellings of those words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the sentence requires "the then ...", however it does not require a hyphen in then current (yet it is certainly commonly seen).

I would also not spell cognizant with a "z", but that is an Australian-English preference for the consistent use of "s".

Comment: Thank you!! is there a reasoning behind then-current vs then current?

Comment: I'm sure some searching would provide a lot of detailed discussion.  But to my mind, there needs to be a definite pause between "then" and "current", or any other word where this is used (the then president, etc).  But putting a hyphen in not only looks untidy, but it eliminates the required pause.

Comment: @Cargill Yes, I wouldn't use a hyphen, as you said it looks very messy.

Comment: We usually spell it with a ‹z› in American English.  Take a look at [GloWbE](http://corpus.byu.edu/glowbe/?c=glowbe&q=43316157) if you want to see how often each spelling is used in different countries.